# How to change link color of an active page in navigation bar of master page. Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, css

I've created a navigation bar in master page that has links of different content pages.As content pages are inhering navigation bar of master page and I want to change color of current page loaded in browser. I've written code in asp.net but it is not working. Here is my code:

> Master Page  site1.Master.aspx

```html
<a href="Homepage.aspx">Home</a>
    <a href="About.aspx" id="about" runat="server">About us</a>
    <a href="Contact.aspx" id="contact" runat="server" >Contact</a>
    <a href="Login.aspx" id="login" runat="server">Login</a>
           <%-- <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>--%>
```

> site1.Master.cs

```
    public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().EndsWith("About.aspx"))
            {
                abc.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:red");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> site1.Master.designer.cs

```
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor about;
     protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor contact;
     protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor login;
```

Comment: try abc.Style.Add("background-color", "red");

Comment: if this doesn't work try to check your condition

Answer (score -1):

Typo error `bacgroud-color:red` to `background-colo:red`

```
abc.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:red");
```

Comment: yes I have updated my code but still its not working